# How to export data into html or txt file using python script runnig on server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The main purpose of my python script is to parse website, and then save results as html ot txt file on server. And also I want this script to repeat this operation every 15 minutes without my action.
Google App Engine doesn't allow to save files on server, instead I should use DataBase. Is it real to save txt or HTML in DB? And how to make script running without stopping?
Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: What is your purpose for saving the site? A little more context may help.

Comment: txt or HTML file will be downloaded by android app. Android app will show it in appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that it is impossible to save files directly to the server. Your only option is the datastore as you say. The data type best suited to you is probably the "Text string (long)", however you are limited to 1mb. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities for more information.

Regarding the scheduling, you are looking for Cron jobs. You can setup a Cron job to run at any configurable period. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron for details describing how Cron jobs work.

Comment: Can you suggest another free service that will be working with python and allow to write files on server?

Comment: Why can't you process the site on a demand basis as apposed to storing the site? Are you passing a static site that will never change?

Comment: Nope, site is dynamic. Content in it updates once in 15-20 minutes.
I can code parser in JAVA, but the page which I'll download to parse will be much bigger than already parsed html file.